# How stop sketch in tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have few line of code here which draw circle in `tkinter canvas` but want i want to do is to stop the sketch to the point where it started so i use sleep but i stop the sketch where it has gotten to then it continue.

So i wrote this function

```
def stop_extent():

    canvas.create_arc(0, 0, 0, 0, extent=0, outline="red", tags=("arc",))
    extent = float(canvas.itemcget("arc", "extent"))
    extent = extent + 5.0
    canvas.itemconfigure("arc", extent=extent)
    canvas.after(100, stop_extent)
```

and set all the values to `0` but still it doesn't stopped it and the label doesn't configure too.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time



def change_extent():
    l.config(text="sketch in progress...")

    canvas.create_arc(350, 100, 220, 220, extent=0, outline="yellow", tags=("arc",))
    extent = float(canvas.itemcget("arc", "extent"))
    extent = extent + 5.0
    canvas.itemconfigure("arc", extent=extent)
    canvas.after(100, change_extent)



def stop_extent():
    l.config(text="sketch stopped...")
    time.sleep(10)
    l.config(text="sketch stopped...")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, background="dodger blue")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


l = tk.Label(canvas, bg="dodger blue",  fg="white")
l.place(x=250, y=20)


b= tk.Button(canvas, text="Start sketch", command=change_extent, width=25, fg='dodger blue')
b.place(x=220, y=330)


b= tk.Button(canvas, text="stop sketch", command=stop_extent, width=25, fg='dodger blue')
b.place(x=220, y=370)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the call back generated by `canvas.after` in the `change_extent` method, and cancel it with `canvas.after_cancel` in the `stop_extent` method; in the following example, I use a global variable `stop` to demonstrate it.

Using `time.sleep` in a GUI application is generally a bad idea.

You also do not need to recreate the arc each time you want to modify its extent, but that is outside the scope of your question.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


def change_extent():
    global stop
    l.config(text="sketch in progress...")
    extent = float(canvas.itemcget(arc_item, "extent"))
    canvas.itemconfigure("arc", extent=extent+5)
    stop = canvas.after(100, change_extent)


def stop_extent():
    l.config(text="sketch stopped...")
    print(stop)
    canvas.after_cancel(stop)
    canvas.itemconfigure("arc", extent=0)   # <- reset to straight line start



stop = None
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, background="dodger blue")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

arc_item = canvas.create_arc(350, 100, 220, 220, extent=0, outline="yellow", tags=("arc",))


l = tk.Label(canvas, bg="dodger blue",  fg="white")
l.place(x=250, y=20)


b= tk.Button(canvas, text="Start sketch", command=change_extent, width=25, fg='dodger blue')
b.place(x=220, y=330)


b= tk.Button(canvas, text="stop sketch", command=stop_extent, width=25, fg='dodger blue')
b.place(x=220, y=370)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks but i want the sketch to go back to the point where it starts to sketch with straight line.

Comment: I updated the answer to reset the arc. please let me know if that is what you wanted.